# error plugins learnpress in wordpress

Tags: plugins

Error when running plugins learnpress in wordpress

> Warning: include(/home/user/public_html/domain/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/templates/single-course/enroll-button-new.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/domain/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/inc/lp-template-functions.php on line 1227

Warning: include(/home/user/public_html/domain/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/templates/single-course/enroll-button-new.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/domain/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/inc/lp-template-functions.php on line 1227

Inside the File lp-template-functions.php on line 1227

```
do_action( 'learn_press_before_template_part', $template_name, $template_path, $located, $args );

include( $located );

do_action( 'learn_press_after_template_part', $template_name, $template_path, $located, $args );
```

view all file 
https://github.com/LearnPress/LearnPress/blob/master/inc/lp-template-functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the file is missing but its has been called from one of the files.

After further review of the plugin files I saw that inside the LearnPress->inc directory in lp-core-functions.php file at 2291 line it adding the filter to add that missing file however that file is not inside the template files. Developer of the plugin has moved all the buttons file inside buttons.php in template folder without updating that filter.

So the solution is to remove that filter manually until the developer fix the issue or  you can manually go the lp-core-functions.php file and comment out line 2291 like below

`// add_filter( 'learn_press_get_template', '_learn_press_enroll_button', 1000, 5 );`

Or you can add this line to removed that filter in somewhere in your theme functions.php

```
`remove_filter( 'learn_press_get_template', '_learn_press_enroll_button');`
```